# How to disable default 1000 max-parameter limit in JBoss 7.0.9?

Tags: jboss

We migrated a web application from JBoss 5.1 to 7.0.9. Post migration, in a specific scenario, there is a Runtime Exception thrown as mentioned below which we didn't encounter with JBoss 5.1. We found there is a restriction on maximum http parameters with default value of 1000 to prevent hash collision based DOS attacks.

**1**. Is it possible to disable this limitation in JBoss 7.0.9?

**2**. If can't, how to conclude/determine the maximum value for a given application?

> java.lang.RuntimeException: io.undertow.util.ParameterLimitException:
>   ***UT000047: The number of parameters exceeded the maximum of 1000***
>                   at io.undertow.server.handlers.form.FormData.add(FormData.java:78)
>   [undertow-core-1.3.31.Final-redhat-3.jar:1.3.31.Final-redhat-3]
>                   at io.undertow.server.handlers.form.FormData.add(FormData.java:68)
>   [undertow-core-1.3.31.Final-redhat-3.jar:1.3.31.Final-redhat-3]
>                   at io.undertow.server.handlers.form.FormEncodedDataDefinition$FormEncodedDataParser.doParse(FormEncodedDataDefinition.java:172)
>   [undertow-core-1.3.31.Final-redhat-3.jar:1.3.31.Final-redhat-3]
>                   at io.undertow.server.handlers.form.FormEncodedDataDefinition$FormEncodedDataParser.parseBlocking(FormEncodedDataDefinition.java:251)
>   [undertow-core-1.3.31.Final-redhat-3.jar:1.3.31.Final-redhat-3] Caused
>   by: io.undertow.util.ParameterLimitException: UT000047: The number of
>   parameters exceeded the maximum of 1000
>                   ... 38 more

Answer (score 5):

The default is 1000, you can modify the value by adding the "max-parameters" as shown below :

```
 <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:undertow:1.1">
            <buffer-cache name="default"/>
            <server name="default-server">
                <http-listener name="default" socket-binding="http" max-parameters="5000"/>
                <host name="default-host" alias="localhost">
............ <snip> ..........
```

Answer (score 0):

make sure your standalone.xml has "max-parameters" set to 5000 like -

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:undertow:10.0" default-server="default-server" default-virtual-host="default-host" default-servlet-container="default" default-security-domain="other" statistics-enabled="${wildfly.undertow.statistics-enabled:${wildfly.statistics-enabled:false}}">
        <buffer-cache name="default"/>
        <server name="default-server">
            <http-listener name="default" socket-binding="http" redirect-socket="https" enable-http2="true" max-parameters="5000"/>
            <https-listener name="https" socket-binding="https" security-realm="ApplicationRealm" enable-http2="true"/>
            <host name="default-host" alias="localhost">
                <location name="/" handler="welcome-content"/>
                <http-invoker security-realm="ApplicationRealm"/>
            </host>
        </server>
        <servlet-container name="default">
            <jsp-config/>
            <websockets/>
        </servlet-container>
        <handlers>
            <file name="welcome-content" path="${jboss.home.dir}/welcome-content"/>
        </handlers>
    </subsystem>
```